# Ethereum wallet shows it has ethers but geth does not show the balance

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth, ether

I am starting to learn ethereum. I have downloaded the Ethereum Wallet, created two accounts and using Rinkeby faucet I got 3 ethers in one of the account. I can see the balance in my wallet. I then ran `geth --testnet --datadir d:\data` and it started syncing. I let it run for a day and now it slowly adds new blocks. I started another get console and attached it to get.ipc. On the console, I did:

> eth.accounts

I see both the accounts in my wallet with first account set as coinbase. But when I ran

> eth.getBalance(accounts[0])

I get `0` balance. What might be something I might have overlooked? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you send it to the other account? What do you get if you try `eth.getBalance(accounts[1])`?

Comment: I did not transfer anything to any accounts, both accounts show 0 in geth console but in wallet the first account show 3 ethers and second account show 0

Comment: What happens when you try `eth.syncing`?

Comment: I get false, when I tried miner.start() I could see 'Commit new mining work' so I take it syncing complete

Answer (score 1):

connect to Rinkeby faucet using metamask chrome extension. Provide your account details there you can check that you received ether or not.

Answer (score 0):

It will show you the balance once it has completed syncing. For me it took more than one day to sync, then I could see the account balance properly.

Try `eth.syncing` to check the status and if `eth.blockNumber` gives `0` as output that means syncing hasn't finished yet.